# How to push a Docker container to Docker Hub only if the build succeeded without an error?

Tags: docker, shell

Since Docker Hub does not allow automatic builds I had to find a solution to build an image every 6 hours on my NAS and push it to Docker Hub. But I feel nervous about my basic and naive script:

```
docker build --no-cache -t name/myserver:latest .
docker push name/myserver:myserver:latest
```

What happens if the build has errors? Do I push a broken image to Docker Hub? How can I make sure I only push the image if the build succeeded? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker push` won't allow you to push a broken image, the command is simply going to fail. What is more likely to happen is that your `docker build` fails so there is no new image present and you then try to push the old image (since the new `name/myserver:myserver:latest` wasn't build due to errors).

You can avoid all these downfalls simply by using `&&` in your script:

```sh
docker build --no-cache -t name/myserver:latest . && \
docker push name/myserver:myserver:latest
```

This ensures that `docker push` is only going to be executed if `docker build` succeeds.

Comment: Tip: _in a shell script_  the slash "\" is not needed and can be removed. Just after `&&` you can do newlines (and lines with comments).